# (Magento\Ui\Model\Bookmark) with the same ID "0" already exists

Tags: magento2, error, admin-panel

I got this error when trying to access the **`Content >> Pages`** in admin panel.
Can anyone help me please.

Comment: what error you are getting. can you share screenshot

Comment: Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.

Comment: How do you reset the filter to its original state?